# Connecting two different hardware simultaneously with expandable GPIO module

Tags: gpio

I'm a beginner to RPI and owns RPI Model B. I've a plan to add 3.2" inch tft touch screen display in GPIO port. However, I have other plan to measure the Humidity values using the humidity sensor which again need to use GPIO. Since the GPIO port is already used by display panel, can I add some gpio expandable module and proceed further?

long story short, is it possible to use display panel and sensor simultaneously with help of expandable gpio module.

Kindly let me know if there are any other external module to accomplish this task. I'm quite stucked up as there are huge results popping up from Google for expanding gpio.

Please advise on this as I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: The pinout guides at [pinout.xyz](https://pinout.xyz/) can be very helpful for figuring out which pins are being used by which boards.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.

Comment: Assuming that they don't have pin conflicts this may work https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/mini-black-hat-hack3r

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify the GPIO actually used by your display.

You can use any GPIO not used by the display assuming you can physically attach a wire to them.

If you can't get access to the GPIO from above you can always solder wires to the underside of the expansion header.